# Strange issue with colours on social icons

Tags: html, css, wordpress, icons

I have very strange issue with Social Warfire social icons. When i set to be inserted into every post, buttons have some strange background colour, and when close to it, change hover to white. This is issue with colours:

[image]

and this is issue with hover when close to it

[image]

This is [URL](http://jitkasimkova.cz/the-grid-snl-performance/) where can be seen the problem. And [here](http://jitkasimkova.cz/2-2/) is shown how need to looks as normal. (close to icon)

This is CSS for that class:

`.nc_socialPanel:not(.nc_floater):not(.nc_socialPanelSide)`

Answer (score 0):

looks like comment from @neil-pearce was usefull. I Fixed myself following this manual from developers:

https://warfareplugins.com/support/my-icons-are-the-wrong-color/

and fixed with this CSS:

```
  a.nc_tweet {
 background-color: initial !important;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.